# Android Wear: How to connect and send data

Tags: android, wear-os

I tried different Android Wear tutorials and documentations, but keep on failing. So little by little, my first steps here. All I want (at the end) is to send a string "hello world" from my mobile device to android wear (Moto 360). What I did so far in Android Studio:

Mobile app:
Added to manifest

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

In my onCreate in the mobile project:

```
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(Wearable.API).build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

And of course I implement

```
public class HandheldMain extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
```

in my class

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle)
{
    Log.v("Test", "on Connected");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult)
{
    Log.v("Test", "on Connection failed" + connectionResult.toString());
}

  @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i)
    {
        Log.v("Test", "on suspended");
    }
```

Questions:
My callbacks never get called. Should them get called when my watch is connected to my phone? Or do I need some kind of code on my watch?

Of course as long as I don't have code on my watch I cannot send a message, but I still struggle to do the connection. I tried several tutorials but they don't seem to work. E.g. https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/a-guide-to-the-android-wear-message-api/152

EDIT:
I found a blocking connect command

```
ConnectionResult a =  mGoogleApiClient.blockingConnect(2000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );
                Log.v("Test", "on Create" + a.getErrorCode());
```

When I run this on a thread it returns "0" so this seems to work - which puzzels me even more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add connectionCallbacks to your GoogleApiClient like this

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addApi(Wearable.API)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this) // this also can be usefull
    .build();
```

Comment: yes, that's it. so either the link I gave above is simply wrong or the behavior has changed over time. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Have you try [Teleport](https://github.com/Mariuxtheone/Teleport) a simple data sync and messaging lib?

Comment: No I haven't and I am not keen to do so, there is standard in Android. It is so simple that it should work.